# How to nginx rewrite setting non trailing slash to trailling slash

Tags: nginx

i have problem with my rule on rewrite (redirect) rules in Nginx.

this is my current setting

```
location /new { rewrite ^/new/([^/.]+)/$ /new/index.php?id=$1 last; }
```

1. www.mysite.com/new/33/ -> it is okay
2. www.mysite.com/new/33 -> error not found

so, my question is: i want to redirect non trailing to trailing slash.

Comment: try_files $uri $uri/; # (or similar)

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the final `/` optional by adding a `?`. For example:

```
rewrite ^/new/([^/.]+)/?$ /new/index.php?id=$1 last;
```

See [this useful resource](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html) on regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

I would use this configuration:

```
location ~ ^/new/([^/.]+)/?$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /new/index.php?id=$1;
}
```

Here we capture the desired part of the URL already with the `location` statement, and then use `try_files` to first try existing files on the filesystem, and if there isn't any matching file, then pass the request to `index.php`.

You can remove `$uri $uri/` if you do not want to check existing files.

Answer (score 0):

I use the config:

```
/test/([^'.]+)$ /test/index.php?id=$1
```

for my website at [AndroidAPKsBox.com](https://www.androidapksbox.com/) now. 
About the redirection for non trailling slash i do it on the php file:

```
if(substr($_GET['id'], -1) != '/'){ //if no trailling slash then redirect!
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: ".get_bloginfo('url').'/test/'.$_GET['id'].'/');
exit();
```